# How to include uneditable information on a form's display?

Tags: django, django-forms

I am using a django formset containing forms that specify user friendship preferences.

My form fields are:

```
    siteuser_id = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    subscribed = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    ally = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    enemy = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

The goal is to display all of a person's friends and that person's status within the game.

When I display the forms in the formset, I'd like to display the nickname (nicknames are not unique or I would just use it instead of siteuser_id) of the person alongside the friendship preference for that person.

I tried making username a form field, but that makes it editable, and I just want it to display within the table, not be editable.

Help?

Comment: Hi Marcin, I don't want a form field. I just want the information to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you don't necessarily want a form - you could just pass the data in objects to your template.

However, if you do want to do this with a form, you could set a custom `widget` for the form field, and subclass `Widget`. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/.

Comment: I think that will work. I've never made one. I'll give it a try.

Comment: I would have just put the information in the template, except it changes for each form in the formset and I have no way of knowing which form I'm on.

Comment: @FooParty No, you wouldn't "put the information in the template". You would pass the information to the template, and the template would render it.

Comment: OK I made a custom widget and it works!

Comment: @FooParty Great! Feel free to accept and vote up this answer.

Comment: OK. I also posted the code for my widget in case anyone needs it.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `readonly` attribute to the field:

```
username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"readonly": "readonly"}))
```

Makes the field non-editable.

Comment: Hm. That still makes a text box though. I think it's kind of ugly to have a non-editable text box.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using [model formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets) (or using them is an option) you can access the `instance` attribute of the form within the template.

For example:

```
{% for form in formset %}
    {{ form.instance.nickname }}
    {{ form }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the custom widget I made to do this!

Just put this in a widgets.py file in your project:

```
from django.forms.widgets import Widget

class DisplayOnlyField(Widget):

    def __init__(self,attrs=None):
        self.attrs = attrs or {}
        self.required = False

    def render(self, name, value="", attrs=None):
        try:
            val = value
        except AttributeError:
            val = ""
        return val
```

Then in your views.py, put:

```
from projname.widgets import DisplayOnlyField
```

And on the field, it would be:

```
user_name = forms.CharField(widget=DisplayOnlyField())
```